# Change image on button from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below code for aspx file where able to get image .But when i tried to load image from code behind on button click it is not working

```
     <asp:Image ID="imgCaptImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Randomeimage.aspx" />
    
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonRefresh" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/refreshimage.png" CausesValidation="False" />
```

<<"not working">>

```
Protected Sub ButtonRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ButtonRefresh.Click
       
        imgCaptImg.ImageUrl = "~/Randomeimage.aspx"
    End Sub
```

Comment: As the name of the page is "Randomeimage", I assume it returns a random image. In that case, are you sure it is not simply returning the same image so that you don't see a change?

Comment: Randomeimage is a image handler for my application as you can see in the first line code  .I am able to load the image using   <asp:Image ID="imgCaptImg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Randomeimage.aspx" />.But t he problem is with ButtonRefresh_Click

Comment: Is the problem that the button click code is not running? As a quick check, you can put the line `Throw New Exception("Button clicked")` in the handler.

Comment: Yes button click code is not running

Comment: It could be that you forgot to rebuild the project after adding the button code. Otherwise, deleting the button from the designer, deleting the code, and then re-creating it often makes it work.